# Passing model through jquery using ajax call is not working properly

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
function getData()
{

 var data = new PostData(DataModel);
 processAjaxRequest('/Home/List', 'Post', 'fetchComplete', data);
}

var DataModel =
{

"AccountName": document.getElementById("Account").value,
"AccountKey": document.getElementById("AccountKey").value,
"Id": document.getElementById("Id").value,
"DateTime": document.getElementById("DateTime").value

}

function processAjaxRequest(urlToProcess, httpMethod, successCallback, postData) {

var dataToPost = '';
if (typeof postData != 'undefined') {
    dataToPost = postData.DataToPost;
}

$.ajax({
    url: urlToProcess,
    type: httpMethod,
    data: dataToPost,
    success: function (data, status) {
        var fn = window[successCallback];
        fn(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, desc, err) {
        processAjaxError(xhr, desc, err);
    },
});
}

var PostData = function (dataToPost)
{

   this.DataToPost = dataToPost;
}
```

I am having value in the textboxes but model's property remains empty.

Comment: Can you check what dataToPost gets set to ? Do a console.log at that point. I don`t think that DataToPost is in scope (at least as you would want it to be)

Comment: @avrono- DatatoPost is setting older value of textbox not the current value.

Comment: Can you show us the value of dataToPost before the $.ajax call ?

Comment: @avrono -It is showing undefined

Comment: @avrono I am thinking the problem is dataModel it is not filling current values.

Comment: Exactly ! You need to create an instance of the PostData object, see something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143033/which-is-better-javascript-object-pattern

Comment: @avrono-I got your point, but not able to do it.

Comment: What can't you do ? What is going wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var PostData =(function() {

    this.DataToPost = "";

    PostData.prototpye = {
      setData: function(dataToPost) {
          this.DataToPost = dataToPost;
      },
      getData: function() {
          return this.DataToPost;
      }
    }
    return PostData;
})();
```

Then you can set and get the data as follows:

```
var myNewPostData = new PostData();
myNewPostData.setData(someData);
myNewPostData.getData();
```

Then you have the data